# OCMock expect a method called within another method

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

This is an extremely basic question about OCMock expectations. Let's you have an instance method methodA on objectA that calls an instance method methodB on objectA.

```
- (void)methodA {
    [self methodB];
}

- (void)methodB {
    ...
}
```

Now, let's say I want to verify that a partial mock of objectA invokes methodA and methodB. It seems like all you should have to do is:

```
- (void)test {
   id mockObjectA = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:self.objectA];
   [[mockObjectA expect] methodA];
   [[mockObjectA expect] methodB];

   [self.objectA methodA];

   [mockObjectA verify];
}
```

When I run the test, it thinks that methodA was successfully invoked but that methodB was not successfully invoked. What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the mock to forward the method call on to the real object so the implementation will actually run.

```
[[[mockObjectA expect] andForwardToRealObject] methodA];
```

Comment: Glorious, thanks! Looks like I need to read the documentation more carefully. By the way, may want to make a slight edit to your answer for future folks: `[[[mockObjectA expect] andForwardToRealObject] methodA];`